Definition of Polarised Hodge Structure
I'm reading section 7.1.2 of Voison's book.
For a compact Kahler manifold with a Kahler form $\omega$, we have intersection pairing
$$Q(\alpha,\beta) = \int_X\omega^{n-k}\wedge \alpha\wedge \beta$$
From the hard Lefschetz theorem, we know $Q$ is: (1) orthogonal for Hodge decomposition; (2) Up to constant, positive definite on primitive forms.
Then in definition 7.7, the author defines polarised Hodge structure as a pair $(V_\mathbb Z,Q)$ such that $Q$ satisfies (1) and (2) above.
My question is: in the compact Kahler manifold, the positive definite property is only for primitive forms, but why in the definition of Hodge structure, it seems the positive definite is for all (p,q) classes? (Also in Wikipedia, positive definite is for all classes in $H^{p,q}$)


The short story is that they're talking about the inner product that a Kahler metric induces on cohomology, which coincides up to a constant with this intersection product $Q$ on primitive $(p,q)$-forms.
For the long story, let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold of dimension $n$, and let $h$ be a Kahler metric on $X$ with Kahler class $\omega$. Hodge theory and harmonic forms give us the Hodge star operator $*$ in cohomology that only depends on the class $\omega$ and not the metric $h$. We then get a Hermitian inner product on $k$-classes $u,v$ by setting
$$
\langle u, \bar v \rangle = \int_X u \wedge * \bar v.
$$
A basic result of Hodge theory is that the Hodge decomposition is orthogonal with respect to this inner product, which means it satisfies (1) and (i) in your original conditions. If $u$ and $v$ are primitive $(p,q)$-forms with $p+q = k$ then
$$
*\bar v = (-1)^{k(k+1)/2} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} i^{q-p} L^{n-k} \bar v
$$
so if I have for once not made any sign errors we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle u, \bar v \rangle
&= \int_X u \wedge (-1)^{k(k+1)/2} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} i^{q-p} L^{n-k} \bar v
\\
&= (-1)^{k(k+1)/2} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} i^{q-p}  \int_X L^{n-k} u \wedge \bar v
\end{align*}
$$
meaning that in particular we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\|u\|^2
&= (-1)^{k(k+1)/2} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} i^{q-p}  \int_X L^{n-k} u \wedge \bar u
\\
&= \frac{1}{(n-k)!} i^{q - p - k} (-1)^k (-1)^{k(k-1)/2} \, i^k H(u)
\\
&= \frac{1}{(n-k)!} i^{p - q - k} (-1)^{k(k-1)/2} \, i^k H(u),
\end{align*}
$$
where I leave to the delight of the reader to verify the exponent on $i$ is correct in the last line using that $i^{-m} = (-1)^m i^m$ and that $k = p+q$. In any case, the last line here is the form in Voisin's condition (ii) up to $1/(n-k)!$, which is then positive-definite on primitive $(p,q)$-forms as claimed.

Sorry, I may not get your point correctly. In definition 7.7, $H(u,v)$ should be positive for all (p,q)-classes (not just primitive classes). But in your answer, the positive-definite property is only for primitive (p,q)-form. It seems to me that the definition 7.7 is a stronger assumption.

I'm saying the polarization is defined by the inner product the Kahler metric induces, which is positive-definite. This inner product happens to be a multiple of $H$ on primitive classes, but $H$ does not define the polarization of the whole Hodge structure.

I may misunderstand some obvious thing. But in definition 7.7, she only defines $Q$, not the Kahler inner product. If we only use $Q(u,v)$(which is defined on whole $H^k$), then definition 7.7 implies $i^kQ(u,\bar v)$ should be positive definite on whole $H^{p,q}$(not just primitive classes).

The form $Q$ is only non-degenerate on the whole of $H^k$ (just look at $p=q=1$, where it has one sign on the primitive part and another on the part that's a multiple of the Kahler form). Maybe having a non-degenerate form is enough for the constructions Voisin and friends want to do, but if they want a positive-definite form on all of $H^k$ the only candidate in sight is the one induced by the Kahler class (or whatever ample line bundle they have picked).

Does that mean $Q$ in definition 7.7 should be the Kahler inner product rather than $\int_XL^{n-k}\alpha\wedge\beta$ in complex geometry? Definition 7.7 appears in most of the textbooks about Hodge structure.

In some sense it probably doesn't matter in the end. $Q$ gives a non-degenerate Hermitian form, that defines the same orthogonal decomposition as the inner product the Kahler class gives and agrees with it up to various constants on primitive forms, which is just as good as having an inner product if you don't have to rely on it being positive-definite. But yeah, I looked up some references and a lot of them claim $Q$ is positive-definite on all of some $H^{p,q}$, which is just not true.
